# How to find execution time instead of execution + fetch in DBeaver

Tags: dbeaver

Is there any way to see actual query execution time in DBeaver while running SELECT statements in PostgreSQL? I'm only seeing `X row(s) fetched - XXms` in the Results window and what I'm interested in for benchmarking purpooses is the actual execution time (without fetching).

Answer (score 8):

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT x FROM y
```

From PostgreSQL documentation https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/using-explain.html:

> The Execution time shown by EXPLAIN ANALYZE includes executor start-up
>   and shut-down time, as well as the time to run any triggers that are
>   fired, but it does not include parsing, rewriting, or planning time.
>   Time spent executing BEFORE triggers, if any, is included in the time
>   for the related Insert, Update, or Delete node; but time spent
>   executing AFTER triggers is not counted there because AFTER triggers
>   are fired after completion of the whole plan. The total time spent in
>   each trigger (either BEFORE or AFTER) is also shown separately. Note
>   that deferred constraint triggers will not be executed until end of
>   transaction and are thus not considered at all by EXPLAIN ANALYZE.

This is a client independent way of evaluating the query execution time.

Answer (score 4):

Go to menu "SQL Editor" -> "Explain Execution Plan" or ctrl+shift+e shortcut from keyboard.

https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/wiki/SQL-Execution#execution-plan